# Voluntary transaction priority in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, locking

I'm going to make up some sql here. What I want is something like the following:

```
select ... for update priority 2; // Session 2
```

So when I run in another session

```
select ... for update priority 1; // Session 1
```

It immediately returns, and throws an error in session 2 (and hence does a rollback), and locks the row in session 1.

Then, whilst session 1 holds the lock, running the following in session 2.

```
select ... for update priority 2; // Session 2
```

Will wait until session 1 releases the lock.

How could I implement such a scheme, as the `priority x` is just something I've made up. I only need something that can do two priority levels.

Also, I'm happy to hide all my logic in PL/SQL procedures, I don't need this to work for generic SQL statements.

I'm using Oracle 10g if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to interrupt an atomic process in Oracle like you're suggesting. I think the only thing you could do would be to programmaticaly break down your larger processes into smaller ones and poll some type of sentinel table. So instead of doing a single update for 1 million rows perhaps you could write a proc that would update 1k, check a jobs table (or something similar) to see if there's a higher priority process running, and if a higher priority process is running, to pause its own execution through a wait loop. This is the only thing I can think that would keep your session alive during this process.

If you truly want to abort the progress of your currently running, lower priority thread and losing your session is acceptable, then I would suggest a jobs table again that registered the SQL that was being run and the session ID that it is run on. If you run a higher priority statement it should again check the jobs table and then issue a kill command to the low priority session (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/KillingOracleSessions.php) along with inserting a record into the jobs table to note the fact that it was killed. When a higher-priority process finishes it could check the jobs table to see if it was responsible for killing anything and if so, reissue it.

Answer (score -1):

That's what resource manager was implemented for.

Comment: hrm, are you sure about that... resource manager will give priority (cpu/io) as you've allocated it, but locks will still work exactly the same as far as I'm aware, just because one session has more resources allocated to it doesn't mean its locks can get stolen.

Comment: This is not correct. The database resource manager avoids priority inversion problems.

Comment: can you provide an example of using the resource manager to solve this problem?